# Azure DevOps access to Variables in Web Extension

Tags: azure-devops

I need an access to a global Variable for a Web Extension written in Html/JavaScript.

**Extension Manifest:**

```
"targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "coverage-web-hub",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-build-web.build-release-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Coverage",
                "uri": "index.html"
            }
        }
    ],
```

[image]

Is there a way to get access to to a global variable for instance with:

- with the [VSS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=azure-devops)
- or thre REST API

**Is it in general possible to share variables with an extension?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Step: Add Scopes to Extension Manifest**

```
"scopes": [
        "vso.variablegroups_read",
        "vso.variablegroups_manage"
],
```

**2. Step: get your Azure DevOps URL (`inside the VSS.ready() function`)**

```
//GET AZURE DEVOPS SERVER URL
var uri = VSS.getWebContext().host.uri
var project = VSS.getWebContext().project.name
var url = uri + project
```

**3. Step: Auth and Read out your Variable Group by Id (numeric, start at 1)**

```
//AUTHENTIFICATION https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/auth?view=azure-devops
VSS.require(["VSS/Authentication/Services"],
    function (VSS_Auth_Service) {
        VSS.getAccessToken().then(function (token) {

            //FORMAT THE AUTH HEADER
            var authHeader = VSS_Auth_Service.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);

            //REQUEST AZURE DEVOPS GLOBAL VARIABLES
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //USE 'url' FROM STEP TWO HERE
            request.open("GET", url + "/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/1?", false); // 1 = ID OF VARIABLE GROUP; false for synchronous request
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authHeader)
            request.send(null);
            var Json = JSON.parse(request.responseText); //GET VARIABLE GROUP AS JSON
            var Coverage = Json.variables.Coverage.value //VARIABLE NAMED 'Coverage'
            var CoverageHistoryJson = Json.variables.CoverageHistoryJson.value //VARIABLE NAMED 'CoverageHistoryJson'

            console.log("RESULT: " + Coverage)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume, by "global" the OP means "in a project scoped variable group".

In the VSS SDK, the variable group methods are under [`TaskAgentRestClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/taskagentrestclient). So it goes:

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/DistributedTask/TaskAgentRestClient"], 
    function(Srv, TaskAPI)
    {
        const Ctxt = VSS.getWebContext();
        const TaskClient = Srv.getCollectionClient(TaskAPI.TaskAgentHttpClient);
        TaskClient.getVariableGroups(Ctxt.project.name)
            .then(function(Groups)
            {
                console.log(Groups);
                //...
            });
    });
```

You will need `vso.variablegroups_read` under `scopes` in the extension manifest.

Tested on Azure DevOps Services 2020.